# How do I get a specific string that is enclosed in specified strings?

Tags: java, string, substring

How would I get a string that is between two other strings?

ex: I have a string `<str>hello this is stuff</str>` and I want to get what is between `<str>` and `</str>`

thanks in advance

Comment: It might work in this case, but parsing XML with regular expressions is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the title of your question is very bad, I know exactly what you're talking about, and I have had trouble with this before.
The solution is using a [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

An easy way to get the string that is between `<str>` and `</str>` (which I'm guessing will probably just be something different in HTML), is to do this:

First things first initialize a [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) by doing this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<str>(.*?)</str>"); // (.*?) means 'anything'
```

Then, you want to get  a matcher from it, by doing:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(<str>); //Note: replace <str> with your string variable, which contains the <str> and </str> codes (and the text between them).
```

Next, depending on whether or not you want to find the last occurrence of the match, or the first, or all of them, then do these:

`First only`:

```
if (matcher.find()) { // This makes sure that the matcher has found an occurrence before getting a string from it (to avoid exceptions)
    occurrence = matcher.group(1);
}
```

`Last only`:

```
while(matcher.find()) { // This is just a simple while loop which will set 'n' to whatever the next occurrence is, eventually just making 'n' equal to the last occurrence .
    occurrence = matcher.group(1);
}
```

`All of them`:

```
while(matcher.find()) { // Loops every time the matcher has an occurrence , then adds that to the occurrence string.
    occurrence += matcher.group(1) + ", "; //Change the ", " to anything that you want to separate the occurrence by.
}
```

Hopefully this helped you :)

Comment: If you parse XML, there may be a problem with entities, I mean that some symbols must be processed in special way. For example &amp; etc

Comment: @Mixaz I don't necessarily plan on parsing xml but thanks for the heads up anyway :)

Comment: OK. Just in case if you would plan, then you could use an XML parser like described here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html ))

Comment: @Johntroen Your input string certainly looks like XML.  Does it allow character entities?  What if the text between `<str>` and `</str>` has a `<` character in it?

Comment: @VGR that was just pseudo-code (I guess you can call that) the real input string will use other characters :) (and the text between wont be allowed to contain special characters after processing)

Comment: @Johntroen - ah, I see. Well, I believe you can find the same for Java SE when need ))

Comment: @VGR `<` characters doesn't matter with regular expressions, as long as complete specified enclosing strings are not enclosed.

Comment: Yeap, regular expressions are awesome, I would suggest the same if @bernhardkiv didn't already ))

Comment: @bernhardkiv IMO patterns and regular expressions are the same thing. And it is written so at the link your provided https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html ))